# how to use AJAX post in django

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

I pratice how to use ajax in django
I post `img_number` to `def update(request)`  when click the picture
And don't know why the ajax can't get the return value(2)
It always alert "error"

Please help me how to use it correctly  in django 
 Thank you.

list.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        data: { csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}' },
    });

    $(".pic_elect").click(function(){
        var img_number = $(this).attr("img_number");
        $.ajax({
            url: 'update/',
            data: {"img_number":img_number,
            },
            type: 'POST',
            async: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            error: function(){
                alert("error")
                window.location.reload();
            },
            success: function(dataArr){
                if(dataArr == 2){
                    alert('good job!');
                }else if(dataArr==6){ 
                /* jump to another.html */
                }else{
                    alert('系統忙碌中，請稍後再試。');
                    window.location.reload();
                }
            }
        });});});
</script>
<body>
....
{% for sh in shop.images %}
<a class="pic_elect" href="#" img_number={{sh.path}}><img src="http://test/image_store/{{ sh.path }}"   ></a>
{% endfor %}
</body>
```

views.py

```
def update(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        # travel = Traveltime.objects.filter(title=request.POST['title'])
        # travel.update(image_elect=equest.POST['img_number'])
        return 2
```

Firebug said the error is:

```
500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR   
AttributeError at /filter/travel/update/
'int' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Views must always return an HttpResponse object. You need to wrap your data in that.

```
return HttpResponse(2)
```

For more complex data, serialize to JSON before creating the response - in 1.7, there is a JsonResponse class to do that for you.